# Code running on any active sheet instead of sheet1

Tags: vba, excel, slice

The function of this program is to convert data of one cell into rows that is to Split comma separated entries to new rows.

Well I am new to VBA, using the vba code from *stackoverflow* reference question, i tried to limit the code to **sheet1** but whenever i run it, it performs the the task on **active sheet** instead of sheet1.

```
Sub SliceNDice()
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim X
Dim Y
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngCnt As Long
Dim tempArr() As String
Dim strArr

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
objRegex.Pattern = "^\s+(.+?)$"
 'Define the range to be analysed

X = Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp)).Value2
ReDim Y(1 To 2, 1 To 1000)
For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
     'Split each string by ","
    tempArr = Split(X(lngRow, 2), ",")
    For Each strArr In tempArr
        lngCnt = lngCnt + 1
         'Add another 1000 records to resorted array every 1000 records
        If lngCnt Mod 1000 = 0 Then ReDim Preserve Y(1 To 2, 1 To lngCnt + 1000)
        Y(1, lngCnt) = X(lngRow, 1)
        Y(2, lngCnt) = objRegex.Replace(strArr, "$1")
    Next
Next lngRow
 'Dump the re-ordered range to columns C:D

[c1].Resize(lngCnt, 2).Value2 = Application.Transpose(Y)
End With
End Sub
```

Advise required in this regard.

Comment: Try x= .Range instead

Comment: _object define error_ appears.

Comment: Your with command won't do anything unless you use a dot before any child of the worksheet object - like Range. So you will also need .cells and any others I might not have spotted

Comment: I have used .Range as well as Sheet1.Range but I am getting error every time.

Comment: ws.Range, everywhere, and stop using variable names that don't have any meaning, you confuse yourself

Comment: X = ws.Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp)).Value2  , _Application defined or object defined error occurs_

Comment: `X = ws.Range([a1], ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp)).Value2` - without the `ws.` to qualify `Cells` you are trying to say "all the cells in sheet ws that exist between cell A1 and a cell on the active sheet" which doesn't make logical sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, your `With` is pointless if you don't make use of the fact that it allows you to shortcut `ws.Range` (etc) to just `.Range`.

Try changing your code to:

```
Sub SliceNDice()
    Dim objRegex As Object
    Dim X
    Dim Y
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCnt As Long
    Dim tempArr() As String
    Dim strArr

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        objRegex.Pattern = "^\s+(.+?)$"
        'Define the range to be analysed

        '"." is needed to qualify which sheet Range, Cells, and Rows applies to.
        'Without a "." (or a "ws."), each property would refer to the active sheet.
        X = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp)).Value2
        ReDim Y(1 To 2, 1 To 1000)
        For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
            'Split each string by ","
            tempArr = Split(X(lngRow, 2), ",")
            For Each strArr In tempArr
                lngCnt = lngCnt + 1
                'Add another 1000 records to resorted array every 1000 records
                If lngCnt Mod 1000 = 0 Then ReDim Preserve Y(1 To 2, 1 To lngCnt + 1000)
                Y(1, lngCnt) = X(lngRow, 1)
                Y(2, lngCnt) = objRegex.Replace(strArr, "$1")
            Next
        Next lngRow
        'Dump the re-ordered range to columns C:D

        'Only write output if there is something to write
        If lngCnt > 0 Then
            'Need to also specify that the following line applies to ws, rather
            'than to the active sheet
            .Range("C1").Resize(lngCnt, 2).Value2 = Application.Transpose(Y)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you could get rid of the `With ws` block and include the `ws` in front of each property/method that you use on that sheet, e.g.

```
X = ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp)).Value2
```

Comment: Thanks for the correct code, now i realized my mistake.

Comment: One issue arising that if there there is nothing present in the sheet1 then  _ application error _ appearing.

Comment: Is there a reason why you would run the macro on an empty spreadsheet?  (If there is, wrap the final assignment statement with an `If` statement to stop it executing when there is nothing to write out, i.e. `If lngCnt > 0 Then` `.Range("C1").Resize(lngCnt, 2).Value2 = Application.Transpose(Y)` `End If`.  (I assume that is the statement that is crashing.))

Comment: yes, i will call this function to split data every five minutes, some times no data is received on outlook so no data is imported to excel. Thanks once again.